# Фильтрация данных

Tags: php, кодировка, безопасность

Фильтрую данные так:

```
$author = mysql_real_escape_string(trim(htmlentities($_POST['author'])));
```

из за самой главной функции htmlentities, из базы возвращаются вместо русского текста кракозябры, как исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил проблему, заменив htmlentities на htmlspecialchars, ибо в htmlentities заменяются все сущности, то бишь все символы включая буквы, а в  htmlspecialchars только специальные.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте в корне сайта создай файл .htaccess с таким содержанием:

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
```

а файл в котором у тебя находится код

```
"$author = mysql_real_escape_string(trim(htmlentities($_POST['author'])));"
```

должен иметь кодировку utf-8 (без BОМ)